# Accessing osgi bundle from non osgi class

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

can we access osgi bundle from non osgi component for example can we access osgi bundle from non osgi struts2 action. if yes then how
thanks  in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interacting Non osgi with osgi bundles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610764/interacting-non-osgi-with-osgi-bundles)

Answer (score 5):

How is everything deployed, and what do you mean by access?

A bundle is just a jar file, so it can be used in a web service like any other jar.  It is only an OSGi bundle when it is deployed in an OSGi framework.  If you want to use it as a library, then there are no problems, many jars already work this way.  If you want to access OSGi services, that is a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

We can access osgi bundles from another applications

If you have an application which uses an entity class like MyClass.java  when you deploy this entity as a bundle on the Apache Karaf,Eqiunox .. etc. OSGI containers

Another applications which might use same entity bundle which is already installed before

when you copy first tags from which is needed to be used 
then paste it as dependency under your new project pom.xml

doing this

```
<groupId>gobito.enterprise.solution</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
```

paste it to another applications as dependency and you can use 
MyClass.java after you import package "gobito.enterprise.solution"

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>gobito.enterprise.solution</groupId>
    <artifactId>anotherapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
 </dependency>
```